# How to initialize an object within a for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently using Microsoft's Visual Studio 2019 and I'm trying to make a version of tic-tac-toe that allows the user to select the size of the board (3x3, 4x4, 5x5, etc...). I'm using buttons for the user input and I'm stuck on how I would go about initializing the needed buttons depending on the size of the board.

```
if (ThreeByThree)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        Button ("btn" + i) = new Button();              
    }
```

This is the only way I could think about doing this but this results in an error, if anyone has encountered this issue I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Get rid of `.Text`. I'm assuming there's some `Button` array declaration in code you haven't shared.

Comment: You can't declare a variable-Name this way. You could use a button-Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically create variable names, but you could add items to a *list* of buttons:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

if (ThreeByThree)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        buttons.Add(new Button());              
    }
}
```

You can then reference the buttons by index - e.g. `buttons[0]` through `buttons[8]`